# Convert rows to columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a excel in below format
Note:- Values in Column Name will be dynamic. In current example 10 records are shown. In another set of data it can be different number of column name.

[image]

I want to convert the rows into columns as below

[image]

Is there any easy option in python pandas to handle this scenario?

Comment: Check pandas documentation for `pivot` function: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: If this is in Excel why not use PowerQuery

Comment: @norie I receive this in excel format in unix machine and need to provide some kind of automation to convert this. That machine will not have any power query access at that time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @juhat for the suggestion on pivot table. I was able to achieve the intended result with this code:

```
fsdData = pd.read_csv("py_fsd.csv")
fsdData.pivot(index="msg Srl", columns="Column Name", values="Value")
```